# Dynamic Drop-Down Pulling From Database But Option Value Not Working

Tags: php, database, dynamic, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dynamic drop down menu that pulls the city name from a database (and automatically updates as I add new cities) and then when selected goes to that city page. The drop down menu works, but when selecting the city nothing happens. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Here's what I've got

```
 <?php mysql_select_db ("db_name");
     echo "<select name=database><option value='.'>Select Your City</option>";
     $result = mysql_query ("select DISTINCTROW city_head from database order by city_head");
     while ($city_head=mysql_fetch_assoc($database)) {
     echo "<option value="#CityIDPage">".$city_head[city_head]."</option>\n"; }
     echo "</select><p>";
```

?>

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The select field value is the same for every option and to get a new city you have to refresh the page so that PHP queries the database again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<select>` elements to not inherently change the page location when a new option is selected.

You can add this functionality - changing the page location to the value of `value` for the selected option - by adding the following attribute to `select`:

```
onchange="window.location.href=this.options
[this.selectedIndex].value"
```

i.e.,

```
<?php 
    mysql_select_db ("db_name");
    echo "<select name=database onchange=\"window.location.href=this.options
[this.selectedIndex].value\"><option value='.'>Select Your City</option>";
    $result = mysql_query ("select DISTINCTROW city_head from database order by city_head");
    while ($city_head=mysql_fetch_assoc($database)) {
        echo "<option value="#CityIDPage">".$city_head[city_head]."</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select><p>";
```

Note that you must set `value` appropriately for each city; I don't know your database schema, so I cannot advise you there.

Comment: That worked great Cheeken. Thank you! I have a follow-up question. The drop down list is now linking out, but I'm having trouble getting the URL to be dynamic. In short, each city has its own page ID and I can't seem to get the value to echo unique URLs. 

    echo "<option value=".'/city/city.php?id=$CityIDPage'.">"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `$CityIDPage` a variable in the snippet you have there?  What value is being assigned to the `id` with your current implementation, and what value do you want to be assigned to it?  This is a 100% guess because I have no idea what your database schema looks like, but perhaps what you want is `echo '<option value="/city/city.php?id=' . $city_head['id'] . '">' ...`.

Comment: Yes, $CityIDPage is the primary key with a numerical value. So `$city_head` would include the city name and `$CityIDPage` would include a unique record number. 

What I'm trying to make happen is when you click on $city_head in the drop down menu, it takes you to the unique URL reflected by the record number. E.g., `echo '<option value="/city/city.php?ID=$CityIDPage">'`

I realize this isn't right above, but that's what I'm shooting for.